# How to login a user // set a user as logged-in manually in Supabase?

Tags: supabase

I'm using Supabase for auth, and I want to set a user as logged-in using my custom logic. I'm looking for something like the following:

```
if (logic-that-checks-if-user-performed-authentication-criteria) {
    supabase.auth.setUserAsLoggedIn({email: "user@email.com"});
}
```

Is there some way I can do this?

**Clarification:**

`logic-that-checks-if-user-performed-authentication-criteria` would be my own custom authentication criteria, not Supabase's.

**More context:**

I want to add Twitter OAuth2 support as Supabase doesn't support it by default. I want to have my own API routes for handling Twitter OAuth2, and the related credentials would be stored either as `user_metadata` in Supabase's auth table or in my custom user table.

The user would be required to sign up with email-with-magic-link (usual Supabase code). But once they have signed up, they would have an option to connect their Twitter account (my code).

After they have connected their Twitter, they would be given an option to sign in with Twitter alongside the usual email-with-magic-link method. This part would require my original question, I would need to set the user as logged-in after I verify that the user has logged in with Twitter and the Twitter profile matches with the one I have saved in my DB.

Comment: What exactly is this "customer authentication logic" that you mention?

Comment: @dshukertjr I have added more context to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Supabase is concerned, a user is signed in if they are signed in with magic link.

It sounds like what you want to know is whether a user has gone through the Twitter OAuth flow or not. In that case, user metadata might be a good place to store that information.

Once a user goes through the Twitter OAuth flow, you could call the following code to store the fact that the user has gone through Twitter's OAuth flow.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
  data: { hasLinkedTwitter: true }
})
```

You would be able to retrieve this information from the `User` object like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
data.user?.user_metadata.hasLinkedTwitter
```